# Unity 3D: Uploading image showing java.net malformed error

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, image-uploading

[image]Im working on mobile app.Trying to upload an image form sdcard,but there was an error stating "java.net malformed url exception protocol not found ".

```
        WWW localFile = new WWW("file://" + localFileName);
        yield return localFile;
        if (localFile.error == null)
            TraceTxt.text = TraceTxt.text+ "\nLoaded file successfully";
        else
        {
            TraceTxt.text = TraceTxt.text+ "\nOpen file error: "+localFile.error;
            yield break; // stop the coroutine here
        }

        WWWForm postForm = new WWWForm();![enter image description here][2]         
        postForm.AddBinaryData ("file", localFile.bytes, "file://"+localFileName, "image/png");

        WWW upload = new WWW(uploadURL,postForm);        
        yield return upload;
        if (upload.error == null)
            TraceTxt.text =TraceTxt.text+ "\nupload done :" + upload.text;
        else
            TraceTxt.text = TraceTxt.text+ "\nError during upload: " + upload.error;
```

The image gives u the clear idea of the error. 
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the file is simply malformed, print it to the console or set up break point to investigate the full path.

Comment: I have printed it on the screen it self(Once see the image please). The photo is loading successfully from the sdcard.Am sure about that..  @greg

Comment: Try without File Name:/ in the beginning of your path

Comment: "File Name:" is the just string to know the trace.. The actual path starts with "/storage/../..."

Comment: I fixed the error by adding "http://" to the URL. But after that firing another error timed out :( Any help..